# I made a grid on visual basic but when i scroll it disappears. any solutions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I am trying to solve a problem on visual basic where circles are drawn on a grid. However, when the form is scrolled, all graphics disappear beyond what was scrolled, this means that both the grid and the part of the circle which gets hidden disappears. I am using the pen function and I am using the DrawLine and DrawEllipse functions. I would like some help in why this is happening.

Thank you in advance.

```
Public Sub refreshgrid()
    formGraphics.Clear(Color.White)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.LightGray)
    Dim pen2 As New Pen(Color.Gray)
    Dim pen3 As New Pen(Color.Black)
    Dim x1 As Integer = Me.Width
    Dim y1 As Integer = Me.Height

    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash
    pen3.Width = 2

    For x = 0 To x1 Step 10
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen, x, 0, x, y1)
    Next
    For y = 0 To y1 Step 10
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, y, x1, y)
    Next
    For x = 0 To x1 Step 50
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen2, x, 0, x, y1)
    Next
    For y = 0 To y1 Step 50
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen2, 0, y, x1, y)
    Next
    For x = 0 To x1 Step 250
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen3, x, 0, x, y1)
    Next
    For y = 0 To y1 Step 250
        formGraphics.DrawLine(pen3, 0, y, x1, y)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    refreshgrid()
    displaycircles()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Scroll
    formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Me.Refresh()
    refreshgrid()
    displaycircles()
End Sub
```

I believe that the problem is coming from this part of the code

Comment: Don't use `CreateGraphics()`. Subscribe to the `Paint` event of a Control to draw onto its surface. Also, since that's a Form, set its `ResizeRedraw` property to `true`, so it's repainted when you resize it. When you need to redraw a Control, if you change some values, call its `Invalidate()` method

Comment: As Jimi said, NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. There are some lazy GDI+ examples out there that do but they are just examples. Use the `Graphics` object provided by the `Paint` event. Every time a `Paint` event is raised, the control is cleared (sometimes partially, sometimes completely) and repainted. If you don't execute your drawing code on that event, your drawing will be cleared and not repainted, so it disappears. As suggested, call `Invalidate` to raise the `Paint` event yourself. Preferably, calculate the smallest area that may have changed and pass that to `Invalidate`.